# Get the name of the action without the prefix in CakePhp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Is there a way to get the name without the prefix of the current action in CakePHP 2.x, but without using the preg_replace or any other string manipulation method. Basically what I'm looking for is Cake built in method, or variable or any other predefined Cake way.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Please read this [part of the CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-request-parameters) about the request parameters.

It will give you access to what you need, directly without any manipulation.

Basically, inside a controller, you can read `$this->request->params['action']` and there you'll have it.

If by "prefix" you mean the Cake action prefix (like "admin" in ["Admin Routing"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)) then no, you cannot get that directly.

You would have look at both variables:

```
$this->request->params['action']; //action name is here (eg. admin_index)
$this->request->params['prefix']; //cake prefix is here (eg. admin )

// Remove the prefix from the action name
$actionWithNoPrefix = substr($this->request->params['action'], strlen( $this->request->params['prefix']) + 1);
```

Comment: the thing is I want to get from action "admin_index" get only "index". But without any additional string manipulation

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to write "action name with out the prefix" part. My bad

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do that directly. You'd have to remove the prefix from the action with a substr and strlen call. So there is no built in call to get that.

Comment: tnx, I was just wondering if I was doing unnecessary processing.